# Atom suddenly causing a warning malware popup from MacOS Monterey

Tags: atom-editor, macos-monterey, malware-detection

I've been using Atom for years on my Mac. I know it has been end-of-lifed by its dev team. I haven't installed anything new on it like plugins for many months. After the latest MacOS update, I get this popup when trying to open it:
[image: the popup warning]

Does anyone know if there is a way to tell if my copy has somehow become corrupted, or if this is a false positive?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I found out that github revoked the Apple code signing certificate and is now enforcing that. I found the answer on the Atom blog. So, I was able to download an older version and it works well.

Comment: Could you share the link to the old version you downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the info, i think it's the best time to find alternatives on text editors since Atom has been officially sunset (Sublime text?)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the current installation to continue working:

```
$ xattr -cr /Applications/Atom.app
```

I'm not sure what the security risks of this are.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider the Pulsar fork of the Atom project: https://pulsar-edit.dev/

I can't fully vouch for it because I'm just starting to use it, but it looks and feels the same to me.